# Pyinstaller on Python3.6.0 raising tuple error

Tags: pyinstaller, python-3.6

I’am trying to make an executable file from my .py file using pyinstaller. Since I couldn’t resolve problems with encoding on Python2.7 I switched to Python3.6 to avoid it. And this is error I get just after running pyinstaller:[Powershell console:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9A3R.jpg)

Does anybody has any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the latest version of pyinstaller 3.2.1 didn't support python 3.6. (Stable, supports Python 2.7, 3.3–3.5 http://www.pyinstaller.org/downloads.html)

You can download the "Current development code (zip)" and compile it with the following steps:

```
cd bootloader
python ./waf configure build install
cd ..
python setup.py install
```

Comment: but i try it , and make a exe.